# Warning: filter_var() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in

Tags: php, validation, sanitization

In this code I get a warning

Warning: filter_var() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in the last line

```
$check = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$str = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (!filter_var($check, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING)) { //here
```

The problem is this, because without it no exists any warning message

```
 !filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING)
```

What is the reason of this error?

Comment: What is "validate string" supposed to mean anyhow?

Comment: Is this from the Live Chat plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such [filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) as FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING... could you just use is_string?

Comment: It's definitely going to be a string as far as `is_string` is concerned. Noone's going to write `$name = 5;`.

Comment: @Jon: Who is Noone, and what does he have to do with anything?

Comment: It probably should be added to the answer that the OP **probably** meant to use `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`.  This is a simple oversight when cutting and pasting code.  For example, there is both a `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` and `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` filter.  I think this gets to the heart of the question.

Answer (score 5):

As @TaylorOtwell mentioned: There is no filter `FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING`. Now, if you call

```
!filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING)
```

you would get a notice

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING - assumed 'FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING'
```

It seems, that your `error_reporting` doesnt include notices.